# Select time, sum and group by column also for non inserted values which are in different time used

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, group-by

I'm fighting with select.

I have three tables.

**income** table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|ID_income    |ID_time_period    |ID_type_income    |Value|
-----------------------------------------------------------
|1            |1                 |1                 |150  | 
|2            |1                 |2                 |180  |
|3            |1                 |3                 |10   |
|4            |1                 |1                 |150  |
|5            |2                 |1                 |54   |
|6            |2                 |1                 |30   |
|7            |2                 |4                 |20   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**time_period** table:

```
-------------------------------------
|ID_time_period      |Name_of_period|
-------------------------------------
|1                   |1.2018        |
|2                   |2.2018        |
-------------------------------------
```

**type_of_income**:

```
------------------------------
|ID_type_income    |Type     |
------------------------------
|1                 |Tools    |
|2                 |Tax      |
|3                 |Machine  |
|4                 |Fuel     |
|5                 |Other    |
------------------------------
```

My target is receive table where I have sum for values for each time period and in each period also for all kind of type income during all time period

```sql
SELECT 
    time_period.Name_of_period AS period, 
    type_of_income.Type AS Type, 
    SUM(value) AS valuesum 
FROM 
    income 
LEFT JOIN 
    type_of_income ON income.ID_type_income = type_of_income.ID_type_income 
LEFT JOIN 
    time_period ON income.ID_time_period = time_period.ID_time_period 
WHERE 
    time_period.ID_time_period > 0 
    AND time_period.ID_time_period <= 2 
GROUP BY 
    time_period.Name_of_period, Type 
ORDER BY 
    time_period.ID_time_period
```

Statement for creating and inserting data

```sql
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `income` (
  `ID_income` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_time_period` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_type_income` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `income` (`ID_income`, `ID_time_period`, `ID_type_income`, `Value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 150),
(2, 1, 2, 180),
(3, 1, 3, 10),
(4, 1, 1, 150),
(5, 2, 1, 54),
(6, 2, 1, 30),
(7, 2, 4, 20);

CREATE TABLE `time_period` (
  `ID_time_period` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name_of_period` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `time_period` (`ID_time_period`, `Name_of_period`) VALUES
(1, '1.2018'),
(2, '2.2018');

CREATE TABLE `type_of_income` (
  `ID_type_income` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `type_of_income` (`ID_type_income`, `Type`) VALUES
(1, 'Tools'),
(2, 'Tax'),
(3, 'Machine'),
(4, 'Fuel'),
(5, 'Other');


ALTER TABLE `income`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_income`);

ALTER TABLE `time_period`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_time_period`);

ALTER TABLE `type_of_income`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_type_income`);


ALTER TABLE `income`
  MODIFY `ID_income` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

ALTER TABLE `time_period`
  MODIFY `ID_time_period` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `type_of_income`
  MODIFY `ID_type_income` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
COMMIT;
```

I get a table but not with data which are not exist
I get

```
-----------------------------
|period    |Type   |valuesum|
-----------------------------
|1         |1      |300     |
|1         |2      |180     |
|1         |3      |10      |
|2         |1      |84      |
|2         |4      |20      |
-----------------------------
```

I need output like this

```
-----------------------------
|period    |Type   |valuesum|
-----------------------------
|1         |1      |300     |
|1         |2      |180     |
|1         |3      |10      |
|1         |4      |0       |
|2         |1      |84      |
|2         |2      |0       |
|2         |3      |0       |
|2         |4      |20      |
-----------------------------
```

you can see type_of_income 5 is not mentioned because its not mentioned in income table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in your post that **type_of_income 5 is not mentioned because its not mentioned in income table**.

so you need to take the distinct value of `ID_type_income` from `income` table and do a `cross join` with `time_period`.

Then do a `left join` with `income` table and as a result you can get the sum `value`.

**Method #1** 
Based on your desired output as a tabular format.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID_time_period as period,
    t1.ID_type_income as Type,
    COALESCE(SUM(i.Value), 0) AS valuesum
FROM
    time_period p
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID_type_income FROM income) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN income i ON p.ID_time_period = i.ID_time_period AND t1.ID_type_income = i.ID_type_income
GROUP BY 
    p.ID_time_period, t1.ID_type_income;
```

**Result #1**

> ```
> period | Type | valuesum
> -----: | ---: | -------:
>      1 |    1 |      300
>      1 |    2 |      180
>      1 |    3 |       10
>      1 |    4 |        0
>      2 |    1 |       84
>      2 |    2 |        0
>      2 |    3 |        0
>      2 |    4 |       20
> ```

**Method #2** 
Based on `Name` and `Type` as result instead of `id`

```
SELECT 
    p.Name_of_period AS period,
    toi.Type AS Type,
    COALESCE(SUM(i.Value), 0) AS valuesum
FROM
    time_period AS p
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID_type_income AS typ_inc FROM income) AS t1
    JOIN type_of_income AS toi ON t1.typ_inc = toi.ID_type_income
    LEFT JOIN income AS i ON p.ID_time_period = i.ID_time_period AND toi.ID_type_income = i.ID_type_income
GROUP BY 
    p.ID_time_period, toi.ID_type_income;
```

**Result #2**

> ```
> period | Type    | valuesum
> :----- | :------ | -------:
> 1.2018 | Tools   |      300
> 1.2018 | Tax     |      180
> 1.2018 | Machine |       10
> 1.2018 | Fuel    |        0
> 2.2018 | Tools   |       84
> 2.2018 | Tax     |        0
> 2.2018 | Machine |        0
> 2.2018 | Fuel    |       20
> ```

Refer [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=39e842f776eebd7939dce2f53e067ca4)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need to change the order of the tables -

```
SELECT time_period.Name_of_period as period, 
type_of_income.Type as Type, 
sum(value) as valuesum 
FROM type_of_income
LEFT JOIN income ON income.ID_type_income=type_of_income.ID_type_income
LEFT JOIN time_period ON income.ID_time_period=kvartaly.ID_time_period
WHERE time_period.ID_time_period>0 and time_period.ID_time_period<=2 
GROUP BY time_period.Name_of_period,Type
ORDER BY time_period.ID_time_period
```